# how to stop the duplicates of the elements in list view?

Tags: java, android, listview

I am using a list view in my app. I wanted to get a list of chapters that I inserted but I saw that the list view elements are repeated until the end. However I didn't get the items that I listed it for because the same object keeps on repeating.

Here is the code that I used in my **chapterAdapter.java** and **physics.java**

***chapterAdapter.java***

```
public class chapterAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<model1> models;

    public chapterAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<model1> models) {
        this.context = context;
        this.models = models;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return models.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return  models.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView ==null){
            convertView = View.inflate(context, R.layout.chapters_view,null);
            ImageView images = convertView.findViewById(R.id.chapterImage);
            TextView title = convertView.findViewById(R.id.chapterTitle);
            model1 model1 = models.get(position);
            images.setImageResource(model1.getChapterImage());
            title.setText(model1.getChapterTitle());
        }
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

**physics.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_physics);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    listView1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.chapters_list_view);
    models = chapter_list_details.getList();

    chapterAdapter = new chapterAdapter(physics.this,models);
    listView1.setAdapter(chapterAdapter);

    listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {

            switch( position )
            {
                case 0:  
                    Intent newActivity = new Intent(physics.this, physics.class);
                    startActivity(newActivity);
                    break;
                case 1:  
                    Intent toy = new Intent(physics.this, ModelQuestions.class);
                    startActivity(toy);
                    break;
                case 2:  
                    Intent intent = new Intent(physics.this, chemistry.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Remove  if(convertView ==null) condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please try removing the condition

`if(convertView==null)`